# Materializecss switch element change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, onchange, materialize

In materializecss documentation page there is no api for switch element. I used onclick event that works but two times trigger

Html

```
<div class="switch">
    <label>
      Off
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      On
    </label>
  </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".switch").on("click",function() {

    var status = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked');
    console.log(status)

     $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : "post",
        data : { status : status}
    })

});

// console.log output : false true or true false
```

This event is triggered two times when i change switch position. Console log shows switch current status and changed status. I want to get only changed status. Because ajax call is triggered two times and it occurs database problem on my backend. How can i manage this problem ?

Comment: use a conditional operator

Comment: i used but two times trigger make status both true in first trigger and false in second trigger or vice versa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try doing a change event

```
  $(".switch").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {
        var status = $(this).prop('checked');

         $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : "post",
            data : { status : status}
        })
    });
```

Comment: it is true if want to send only true data but i want to send false data  if switch false

Comment: can you provide the html ?